# Subscribe Subject receive multiple time in row

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Subject to pass information to different page but when i receive my information in the observable I receive it in multiple time while I send it only one time
I'm guessing the problem is coming cause i change page after it

My Subject

```
public handleUpdate = new Subject<any>();

updateHandleSearch(): Observable<any> {
    return this.handleUpdate.asObservable();
}

updatingHandleSearch(providerResponse: any) {
    this.handleUpdate.next(providerResponse);
}
```

My observer

```
Main.component.ts
this.dealPageService.updateHandleSearch().subscribe(test => {
    this.dealPageService.isLoading = true;
    this.handleShowAll(test);
});
```

```
SideBar.component.ts
updateSearch(deal) {
    this.router.navigate(['/deals']);
    this.dealPageService.updatingHandleSearch(deal);
}
```

Comment: Try implementing **ngOnDestroy** life cycle hook in your component and unsubscribe from the subject.

Comment: When I unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy no more value is coming

Comment: @BaptisteGoudey that's the point. If you want to keep subscribed you need to keep the component alive or use a service that lives longer than the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that once you subscribe to an Observable you have to unsubscribe from it.

Otherwise you will have a common memory leak.

In demo you have basic app (routing) and two components and one shared service. Every time you navigate to a new route a new component instance will be created and the old one will be destroyed (ngOnDestroy).

If you forget to unsubscribe then the component will remain alive and your subscription will still receive data. Check the console output.

To better identify the component I added an **instanceId** field for console output.

Save your subscription locally:

```
subs: Subscription;
...
this.subs = this.updateHandleSearch.updateHandleSearch()
```

To experiment and resolve the issue uncomment this line:

```
this.subs.unsubscribe();
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxuujh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts) for a working demo.

Comment: or in the other way subs = new Subscription(); subs.add(//subscription), rest the same

Answer (score 0):

yes, you don't use unsubscribe and get multiple values. you also can use .pipe(takeUntil(...)) operators for get unsubscribe effect on your component when use ngOnDestroy method. 
sometimes it very nice help